declaration is incompatible with "const T *const Table<T>::addNewRecord(T data)" and dynamic exception specifications are not permitted in this mode
const T * const addNewRecord(T data) throw (MemoryError,IOError);
this is function declared in header file T is template and MemoryError,IOError is Exception handling functions
template<class T> const T * const Table<T>::*addNewRecord*() (T record) throw (MemoryError,IOError)
{
    T * newRecord = new T (record);
    if(!newRecord)
    {
        throw new MemoryError();
    }
    newRecord->recordId = this->getNextRecordId();
    this->records->push_back(newRecord);
    try
    {
        this->writeTofile();
    }

    catch (IOError error)
    {
        //clean up things
        this->records->pop_back();
        delete newRecord;

        //rethrow exception
        throw;
    }

    return newRecord;
}

this is funtion declared in CPP file .And its showing error mention in title in function name (addRecord) and not picking up the MemoryError,IOError functions and dynamic exception error in throw

Dynamic exception specification was deprecated already in C++11 and has now been removed from the language (C++17 and later). Are you compiling C++98 code?

This is also not a [mcve]

Adding header code will help to fix the problem
